# Suppose on $|z|\le1$, $f(z)$ is holomorphic and $|f(z)|\le1$. Prove that $|f'(0)|\le1$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose on $|z|\le1$, $f(z)$ is holomorphic and $|f(z)|\le1$.

Prove that $$|f'(0)|\le1$$

I know that we usually have to provide some sort of start but I totally have no idea where to begin. We know that $f(z)$ is holomorphic but how does that at all tie to $f'(0)$?
I'm not expecting an answer just some point that i can think about. I feel like i'm forgetting a properity of holomorphism here.

Comment: By [Schwarz-Pick theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem) we have that $|f'(0)|\le 1-|f(0)|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Schwarz lemma we know that $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\le\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$$

Plug $z=0$ and you get $$|f'(0)|\le1-|f(0)|^2$$we also know that $|f(0)|\le1$ so also $|f(0)|^2$ is and thus $|f'(0)|\le1$

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about this lemma.

Comment: @Danxe  But it's easier to use the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f'(0)= \displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(w)}{w^2}dw$

And try to use  Cauchy's estimate

Answer (score -1):

Cauchy's integral theorem gives
$$
f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz
$$
and, considering that the integrand here has absolute value at most $1$, and the contour we are integrating along has length $2\pi$, the integral *cannot* be larger than $2\pi$ in absolute value. The result follows.